# Could someone explain why this inline element moves when using floats nearby?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Could someone explain why this behaviour occurs. In the following code, when I change the property display: inline-block to float:left, the inline text next to it moves slightly. Is there a reason why this occurs?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Float Right</h2>
    
    <p>In this example, the image will float to the right in the paragraph, and the text in the paragraph will wrap around the image.</p>
    
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; border:red solid 2px; ">Sample</div>
    <div style="display: inline;color:green; border:green solid 2px;">Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there something specific you want to achieve?

Comment: not really, I just wanted to know why the inline element behaves the way it does when next to a floated element in comparison to the inline-block, for future reference